# Widening the x-axis by a specific factor?

Tags: python, scale, axis, xscale

I am trying to plot data in a simple scatter plot.

I am able to this pretty well with the data I have, the only issue is that, as a result of the experiment I was running, the x-axis is actually off.

The x-axis is the position of an object and it is crucial for my work to point out the distance at certain points. However, the data I have is not scaled correctly.

As an example, one relevant distance is 0.02 mm on the plot but I want it to be 0.38 mm (because this is the value it actually was in the experiment).

Is there a way to scale the x-axis so that it accurately portrays the projected distance while keeping all y-values the same (the y-axis is fine)?

I know the value by which I need to multiply the distances in the plot to get the correct distance (roughly 19) but how can I change the x-axis in the plot so that this information is readily there for the viewer?

I guess in a way I want to widen the x-axis by a factor? Is this possible?

Comment: Why not simply correct the data before plotting it?

Comment: I wish I could but the way in which the data was taken did not allow that (for some reason not in my control) and it is already after the fact (I can no longer repeat the experiments), so I have to work with the data I have.

Comment: I don’t mean correct it in the past—I mean rescale it when making the plot.